# How RFID does not conflict when reading multiple cards?

Tags: rfid

I pass on the metro this morning with 2 RFID card on my wallet, one is my metro pass and another my enterprise pass.

How the reader know exactly which read? How it do not conflict between cards?

I already search on the web but only find extensive datasheets with a lot technical information, I'm not expert enough to find this answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Your googling powers are weak, old man ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification#Signaling

Comment: Google "RFID anti-collision" http://www.rfidjournal.com/blogs/experts/entry?9271

Comment: Reading on the "1-wire" devices search algorithm may help explain a solution for wired devices in more detail. See [Maxim application note AN-187](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/187).